# Determine the convergence or divergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive terms so that $a_n=\frac{2008^n}{n^{2008}}$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I need to determine the convergence or divergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$.

Anyone can help me? Any help much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: $$lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \infty$$ so it has to be divergent, right?

Comment: even $a_n$ itself doesn't converge. Let alone the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{2008^n}{n^{2008}}}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{2008}{\left( n^{1/n}\right)^{2008}}=\dfrac{2008}{\left( \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n^{1/n}\right)^{2008}}=\dfrac{2008}{1^{2008}}=2008>1$.

what does the root test say ?

> Proof of $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$.
>
> Notice that for each $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{1\}$, $n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1+a_n$ for some $a_n>0$.(if $n>1$ then $n^{\frac{1}{n}}>1$)
>
> Let $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{1\}$. Then
>
> $n=(1+a_n)^n=1+na_n+\frac{n(n-1)}{1.2}a_n^2+\dots +a_n^n>\frac{n(n-1)}{2}a_n^2$.
>
> Since $a_n>0$ we have $0<a_n<\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}$. Also since $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}0=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}=0$ we have that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$. Therefore $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(a_n+1)=1$.